# Spring Boot return a List of Objects in a GET-RestAPI

Tags: json, rest

i hope somebody can help me. That is my return statement of my get- method : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac8nB.png)

When i use Postman to test my get-method i get the following answer:  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btDXJ.png)

So far so good. But the tests are failing : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zQSo.png)

The assertionerror : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhIIy.png)

So what is the problem here? It seems like that the response is not an JSON-Array?  and access on [0] fails. How can i fix that?

I have no idea why its failing. Already tried out everything that i found. Seems like an Json parsing error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's simple, it mentions that , something which should not be null is actually null , hence your assertion is failing. Can you check if the test data is being populated properly ?